# Split the second column of txt and take specific value

Tags: python

I have file `household_power_consumption.txt` that contains the minute level power consumption of a family. The first two columns are time and the third column is the consumption amount of the minute.
What I need to do is:

1. Calculate hourly average power consumption of the family
2. Plot the power consumption with regard to hours with animation

I encounter at the following line

`hour = result.cut(':', 0)`

the following exception:

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'cut'`

```
f = open('household_power_consumption.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
#get the second column:hour-min-sec
result = []
for x in lines:
    result.append(x.split(';')[1])
#split/cut the first number as hour
hour = result.cut(':', 0)
print(hour)
```

Is there a simple way to convert list to string? And how can I calculate the numbers by the hours we gonna capture?

File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11cLcD3ckRCaXAZrEX6Z06lPaH03i8qXz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please provide sample data as code, not a URL

Comment: Why not just split on the colon and then get the first index. Also omit the first line because it contains the header.

Comment: `...result.cut(':', 0) AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'cut'` - what made you think lists have a `cut` method? You probably need to invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples while referencing [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html).

Comment: @Wamadahama that sounds better as i need to calculate it later as well, how can I do it?

Comment: See Louis Lac's comment on this

Answer (score 1):

you can use `datetime` module from python to convert string to time.

here is a example

```
from datetime import datetime

time_str = '13:55:26'
time_object = datetime.strptime(time_str, '%H:%M:%S').time()
print(type(time_object))
print(time_object)
print("Only Hour",time_object.hour)
```

Comment: That sounds good, but how can i strip the entire second column?

Answer (score 1):

First, it is bad practice to open a file like this, you should use a with-statement to handle exceptions and file closing gracefully:

```py
with open('household_power_consumption.txt', 'r') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
# process lines here...
```

Second, you should ignore the first line (header line) and (optionally) strip the line (to remove the "\n" at the end if you plan on using this last column):

```py
lines = [line.strip().split(";") for line in lines[1:]]
```

Third, the `cut` method does not exists, you should either use the solution given by @Jasar or do this:

```py
hours = [int(line[1].split(":")[0]) for line in lines]
```

This retrieve the second column item and the hour component and convert it to an `int` (else it is a `str`).

Last, prefer list-comprehension instead of this:

```py
result = []
for x in lines:
    result.append(x.split(';')[1])
```

List comprehension:

```py
result = [x.split(";")[1] for x in lines]
```